# why the columns read different in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file. when I run the command df.columns the column names read like the following.

> Index(['sep=', 'Unnamed: 1'], dtype='object')

How to drop or change the column name to what I want.

The second row has the column name what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read the csv file, the `header` keyword parameter allows you to indicate a line in the file to use for header names *(for ex. **header = 1**)*

> **header** : ***int, list of int, None, default ‘infer’***
> Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the data.
> Default behavior is to infer the column names: if no names are passed the behavior is identical to header=0 and column names are inferred from the first line of the file, if column names are passed explicitly then the behavior is identical to header=None...

Or just skip the first line with `skiprows` *(for ex. **skiprows = 1**)*

> **skiprows** : ***list-like, int or callable, optional***
> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file...

The `names` keyword parameter will be useful when you don't have the column name in the file.

> **names** : ***array-like, optional***
> List of column names to use. If the file contains a header row, then you should explicitly pass header=0 to override the column names. Duplicates in this list are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
column_names = ("Column1","Column2")
df.columns = column_names
```

to make the 2nd row of the dataset column names:

```
column_names = df.loc[1].values
df.columns = column_names
```

Comment: this didn't work, many had suggested in other posts but i'll find out why this didn't work.

Comment: I don't know as I haven't encountered this problem before, but the answer above might help. I'd appreciate it if you could let me know when you figured out why this isn't working.